# How many SNMP packets/sec handle by Windows Server 2003/2008/2012?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, snmp, windows-server, network-monitoring

We are monitoring more than 400 devices via SNMP, there is no limitation for number of nodes to monitor, licensed for unlimited nodes

the problem is alarms are malfunctioning, the monitoring software team told windows servers cannot handle more than 100 SNMP packets per second, Is it true?

Comment: I think that you may have been lied to. This question needs much more detail to generate a useful answer.  What are the specs of your server(s)? Your NIC? What monitoring software are you using? What do you mean by malfunctioning alerts?  I've got boxes monitoring 1000+ nodes. But that doesn't really tell you anything about my polling cycles, number of alerts being triggered on, or any custom MIBs that I might be using. Please give us some more details so you can get a better answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not process the SNMP packets, it only hands them over to the monitoring software just like any other network packet. To say that Windows cannot handle 100 SNMP packets per second is saying that Windows cannot handle 100 packets of any kind per second.

That does not mean it is impossible for Windows to be the weakest link, but there are other more likely bottlenecks:

- Your server hardware (mostly CPU and the network interface).
- Your network (cabling, routers, switches, VPN connections, proxies, ..).
- The devices you are monitoring. Devices like IP-phones, printers etc do not have a lot of processing power and may not be able to keep up with the SNMP requests from the server.
- The monitoring software itself.

Comment: I agree with this, and I would like to add that what is crucial for the performance of the monitoring software, is /what it does/ when receiving a trap. I've seen monitoring software that claims to handle thousands of network nodes, with very high trap flows, but it all falls apart as soon as something should /happen/ when a trap arrives. For instance, an alarm should be created in a database, so the database accesses become the bottleneck.